# I am trying to write SML to Take Input from 1st LIST (Let X), Add first X element of 2nd list & store in 3rd list, Stuck in using REF

Tags: sml, mutable

- ri1; // REF stores current index of LIST1
- ri2; // REF stores current index of LIST2
- !ri1=0; //starting from index 0
- !ri2=0; //starting from index 0
- **a function running '!ri1' times, to do following**
- add elements from LIST2(!ri2) to LIST2(!ri2+!ri1);
- store result in LIST3;
- update !ri1=!ri1+1;
- update !ri2=!ri2+!ri1;

Comment: Don't even try this with references and indices. That is not how anyone would write such code in ML, and is far more complicated than necessary. You should be able to express the same in a 3-line recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this `f` does what you want:

```
fun f([], _) = []
  | f(x::xs, ys) = f'(0, xs, x, ys)
and f'(z, xs, 0, ys) = z::f(xs, ys)
  | f'(z, xs, n, y::ys) = f'(z + y, xs, n - 1, ys)
  | f'(_) = raise Empty
```

Comment: Thanx for showing up!

this is what i need to do

List1 [2, 3, 2,1...];    
List2 [2,4,5,6,7,7,8,5,6,3,4,2,2,1,1];   

List1(1)=2 so List2(1)+List2(2) - 2 item summed;     
then List1(2)=3 so List2(3)+List2(4)+List2(5) - 3 item summed;     
then List1(3)=2 so List2(6)+List2(7) - 2 item summed;     ... so on

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your algorithm. Updated the answer. Does that do what you need?